# Проблемы чисел с плавающими точками, энтропия

Tags: oracle, математика, plsql

Представим себе следующую ситуацию

У нас есть 4 столбца

- Сумма без ндс -> `sum_wo_tax`
- Сумма с ндс -> `sum_w_tax`
- Определитель, облагается ли ндс -> `is_wo_nds`
- Исключена ли данная сумма (учитываем ли мы её, или нет) -> `excluded_from_delivery`

Мы хотим посчитать коэффициент на вычет исключенных позиций из заказа, есть формула

```
sum(decode(t.is_wo_nds, 1, t.sum_wo_tax, t.sum_w_tax) * abs(t.excluded_from_delivery)) 
/
sum(decode(t.is_wo_nds, 1, decode(t.sum_wo_tax,0,1,t.sum_wo_tax), decode(t.sum_w_tax,0,1,t.sum_w_tax))) as coef
```

Давайте протестируем её.

Представим что есть 3 позиции, первая на 100, вторая на 100, третья на 0, первая и третья исключены, получается из суммы на 200 мы вычли 100 рублей, что равно коэффициенту 0.5

```
select sum(decode(t.is_wo_nds, 1, t.sum_wo_tax, t.sum_w_tax) * abs(t.excluded_from_delivery)) 
/
sum(decode(t.is_wo_nds, 1, decode(t.sum_wo_tax,0,1,t.sum_wo_tax), decode(t.sum_w_tax,0,1,t.sum_w_tax))) as coef
              from (select 0 as is_wo_nds,
                           100 as sum_wo_tax,
                           100 as sum_w_tax,
                           1 as excluded_from_delivery
                           from dual
                    union all
                    select 0 as is_wo_nds,
                           100 as sum_wo_tax,
                           100 as sum_w_tax,
                           0 as excluded_from_delivery
                           from dual
                    union all
                    select 0 as is_wo_nds,
                           0 as sum_wo_tax,
                           0 as sum_w_tax,
                           1 as excluded_from_delivery
                           from dual) t
```

получаем

```
coef
.4975124378109452736318407960199004975124
```

Странно, но должно было получиться `0.5`

А если убрать все обработки и мы точно понимаем, что в наших расчётах будет участвовать только `sum_w_tax` и `excluded_from_delivery` а то есть

```
select sum(t.sum_w_tax * abs(t.excluded_from_delivery)) /
                   sum(t.sum_w_tax) as coef
              from (select 0 as is_wo_nds,
                           100 as sum_wo_tax,
                           100 as sum_w_tax,
                           1 as excluded_from_delivery
                           from dual
                    union all
                    select 0 as is_wo_nds,
                           100 as sum_wo_tax,
                           100 as sum_w_tax,
                           0 as excluded_from_delivery
                           from dual
                    union all
                    select 0 as is_wo_nds,
                           0 as sum_wo_tax,
                           0 as sum_w_tax,
                           1 as excluded_from_delivery
                           from dual) t
```

мы получаем

```
coef
.5
```

Решение напрашивается в округлении, но нет явного ответа, до какого знака округлять, так как исключение может быть к позиции, где `sum_w_tax` стремится к бесконечности, по отношению к позиции на `sum_w_tax` которая стремится к 0.

[db<>fiddle если нужно](https://dbfiddle.uk/OJZjFvzp)

Неужели `decode` так странно ведет себя?

---

**UPD1**

А что если переписать всё под констуркцию `case when`?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN t.is_wo_nds = 1 THEN t.sum_wo_tax * ABS(t.excluded_from_delivery)
            ELSE t.sum_w_tax * ABS(t.excluded_from_delivery)
        END
    ) / 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN t.is_wo_nds = 1 THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN t.sum_wo_tax = 0 THEN 1
                    ELSE t.sum_wo_tax
                END
            ELSE 
                CASE 
                    WHEN t.sum_w_tax = 0 THEN 1
                    ELSE t.sum_w_tax
                END
        END
    ) as coef
              from (select 0 as is_wo_nds,
                           100 as sum_wo_tax,
                           100 as sum_w_tax,
                           1 as excluded_from_delivery
                           from dual
                    union all
                    select 0 as is_wo_nds,
                           100 as sum_wo_tax,
                           100 as sum_w_tax,
                           0 as excluded_from_delivery
                           from dual
                    union all
                    select 0 as is_wo_nds,
                           0 as sum_wo_tax,
                           0 as sum_w_tax,
                           1 as excluded_from_delivery
                           from dual) t
```

И результат тот же

```
coef
.4975124378109452736318407960199004975124
```

т.е. в принципе условные блоки что-то вытворяют с числами?

[Обновленный db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/suvYenQL)

Comment: Если не округлять, то надо формулу пересматривать, убирать лишние `DECODE` по возможности.

Comment: @DiMithras к сожалению, убрать лишние `decode`'ы невозможно, но может можно убрать `decode` по проверке на 0 в делителе, но, скажем, определитель ндс убрать нельзя

Comment: @DiMithras хотя я могу ошибаться, а что если через `case`...

Comment: Если вот так: "*Коэффициент = Сумма заказа с учетом исключенных позиций / Сумма заказа без учета исключенных позиций*", `SUM(t.sum_w_tax * (1 - t.excluded_from_delivery)) / SUM(t.sum_w_tax)`

Comment: .497 vs .5 - это явно не ошибка округления, а неправильные формулы (алгоритмы) вычислений

Comment: Да по алгоритмам сильно усложняете, но я пока причин для этого не вижу.

Comment: @DiMithras так, окей, впринципе результат получается, но это без учёта определителя НДС, что как бы неполная формула

Comment: Простите, что вмешиваюсь, а использовать тип currency для описания валют - не судьба? В оракуле точно должен быть. Тогда и проблема округления уйдет.

Comment: @Ingvar если интересно, в oracle формально нет типа `curency`, есть форматирование под `curency`, но в нём лежит тип `number`

Comment: @Acinit не буду утверждать точно (давно работал с ним), хотя очень сильно сомневаюсь. В PostgreSQL есть точно. Но на крайний случай есть decimal с заданной точностью. Currency просто хранит до "безнадцати дурильёнов"

Comment: @Ingvar [и не нужно утверждать, достаточно доку открыть посмотреть](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6:~:text=Spatial%20Types.-,Oracle%20Built%2Din%20Data%20Types,-The%20Built%2DIn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN t.is_wo_nds = 1 THEN t.sum_wo_tax
            ELSE t.sum_w_tax
        END * t.excluded_from_delivery
    ) / NULLIF(SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN t.is_wo_nds = 1 THEN t.sum_wo_tax
            ELSE t.sum_w_tax
        END
    ), 0) AS coef
FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS is_wo_nds, 100 AS sum_wo_tax, 100 AS sum_w_tax, 1 AS excluded_from_delivery FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 AS is_wo_nds, 100 AS sum_wo_tax, 100 AS sum_w_tax, 0 AS excluded_from_delivery FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 AS is_wo_nds, 0 AS sum_wo_tax, 0 AS sum_w_tax, 1 AS excluded_from_delivery FROM dual
) t;
```

По комментариям пришли к этому варианту.

Шли от упрощения к усложнению.
Сначала переработали логику:
`SUM(t.sum_w_tax * (1 - t.excluded_from_delivery)) / SUM(t.sum_w_tax)`

Максимально упростили. `1-` в последствии убрали (в комментариях).

Через `CASE` выражение выбираем соответствующую сумму в зависимости от значения определителя НДС `is_wo_nds`. Если `is_wo_nds` равен **1**, берём `sum_wo_tax`, иначе — `sum_w_tax`.

#### Деление на ноль

Самое сильные хитрости были из-за предусмотра деления на ноль. Тут всё можно упростить через `NULLIF(SUM(…), 0)` для знаменателя в выражении деления. Если сумма заказа без учета исключенных позиций равна нулю, то результат деления будет `NULL`, и ошибку деления на ноль избежим.

Comment: @Acinit комментарии про `1-` зря удалили

Comment: перефразировать можно следующим образом, "если вы хотите найти коэффициент остатка, то возьмите 1-.."

Comment: А вообще да, изначально формула предложенная считала коэффициент остатка от вычитания, а нужно было найти коэффициент вычитаемого

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут вот

```
sum(decode(t.is_wo_nds, 1, decode(t.sum_wo_tax,0,1,t.sum_wo_tax), decode(t.sum_w_tax,0,1,t.sum_w_tax))) as coef
```

зачем единицы стоят???

100/201=.4975124378109452736318407960199004975124

Comment: ну затем, что значения могут принимать 0

Comment: а делитель не может быть 0

Comment: Они дают ошибку. Это очень странные рассуждения: давайте добавим что-нибудь, лишь бы не получить ноль :-)

Comment: ляяяя ну и дуранул канеш, спасиб))))

Comment: Либо принимаем, что заказ ненулевой, либо делаем проверку на 0 перед делением.